# TTS stops when phone's screen timesout in Android

Tags: android, text-to-speech

Whenever I start the TTS and keep it  onfor 30 seconds the screen times out and when it happens my TTS pauses and when I again tap the screen to unlock the phone it starts reading again..

Whether there is any way to keep the TTS up and running without pausing at any stage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to use setKeepScreenOn(true);
to keep the screen on.